# NaN !== parseInt(undefined);

Tags: javascript, numbers

How can this be false?

```
console.log(parseInt(undefined));
//NaN
console.log(parseInt(undefined)===NaN);
//false
```

That seems dumb

Comment: Try `console.log(NaN === NaN)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NaN](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.23) is *not* equal to anything, even itself. Use [`isNaN`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4) to detect NaN instead of an equality.

```
NaN === NaN  // -> false
isNaN(NaN)   // -> true (argument is coerced [ToNumber] as required)
x = NaN
x !== x      // -> true (would be false for any other value of x)
NaN || "Hi"  // -> "Hi" (NaN is a false-y value, but not false)
```

This is a result of JavaScript following IEEE-754 and it's (quiet) [NaN lack-of-ordering behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an unordered [not equal] result even when comparing with itself.

See also [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Comment: is it part of quantum physics?

Comment: So this is expected behavior! That explains why I haven't noticed it in all of the [wtf](http://wtfjs.com/) [javascript](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) content I've viewed.

Comment: @iabw Yes, it is expected. I think it is that a direct check comes up rather infrequently. Most code likely coerces the result of such a parseInt as 0 or considers 0/false-y to be invalid (as NaN is still a flase-y value). Also, this NaN behavior wouldn't (shouldn't) surprise people with background in other languages using similar floating point types, which is most of them.

Answer (score 3):

Its because NaN === NaN is also false!

Answer (score 3):

NaN is not equal to itself and the reason can be understood from the answer posted by Stephen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values/1573715#1573715):

> My understanding from talking to Kahan is that NaN != NaN originated
>   out of two pragmatic considerations:
>
> - that `x == y` should be equivalent to `x - y == 0` whenever possible (beyond being a theorem of real arithmetic, this makes hardware
>     implementation of comparison more space-efficient, which was of utmost
>     importance at the time the standard was developed — note, however,
>     that this is violated for x = y = infinity, so it’s not a great reason
>     on its own; it could have reasonably been bent to `x - y == 0 or
>     NaN`).
> - more importantly, there was no `isnan( )` predicate at the time that NaN was formalized in the 8087 arithmetic; it was necessary to provide
>     programmers with a convenient and efficient means of detecting NaN
>     values that didn’t depend on programming languages providing something
>     like `isnan( )` which could take many years.  I’ll quote Kahan’s own
>     writing on the subject:
>
> > *Were there no way to get rid of NaNs, they would be as useless as Indefinites on CRAYs; as soon as one were encountered, computation
> >     would be best stopped rather than continued for an indefinite time to
> >     an Indefinite conclusion. That is why some operations upon NaNs must
> >     deliver non-NaN results. Which operations? … The exceptions are C
> >     predicates “ x == x ” and “ x != x ”, which are respectively 1 and 0
> >     for every infinite or finite number x but reverse if x is Not a Number
> >     ( NaN ); these provide the only simple unexceptional distinction
> >     between NaNs and numbers in languages that lack a word for NaN and a
> >     predicate IsNaN(x).*
>
> Note that this is also the logic that rules out returning something
>   like a “Not-A-Boolean”.    Maybe this pragmatism was misplaced, and
>   the standard should have required `isnan( )`, but that would have made
>   NaN nearly impossible to use efficiently and conveniently for several
>   years while the world waited for programming language adoption.  I’m
>   not convinced that would have been a reasonable tradeoff.